# Grafana on Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, prometheus, grafana

I am using docker to run prometheus, grafana and node exporter. I am trying to use named volumes and I am having some issues with that. My docker-compose code is:

```
version: "3.7"
volumes:      
    grafana_ini:
    
    prometheus_data:
    
    grafana_data:
    
    dashboards_data:
    
services:
  grafana:
    build: ./grafana
    volumes:
            - grafana_ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini
            - grafana_data:/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/datasource.yml
            
            - dashboards_data:/etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards
            - ./dashboards/linux_dashboard.json:/etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/linux_dashboard.json
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    links:
            - prometheus
  prometheus:
    build: ./prometheus
    volumes:
            - prometheus_data:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
  node-exporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter:latest
    container_name: node_exporter
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 9100
```

and my dockerfile for grafana is:

```
FROM grafana/grafana:latest
COPY ./Ini/grafana.ini /etc/grafana/grafana.ini
COPY datasource.yml /etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/datasource.yml
COPY ./dashboards/dashboard.yml /etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards
COPY ./dashboards/server/linux_dashboard.json /etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards
COPY ./dashboards/server/windows_dashboard.json /etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards
EXPOSE 3000:3000
```

and I am getting this error while building it

ERROR: for 2022_grafana_1  Cannot create container for service grafana: source /var/lib/docker/overlay2/4ac5b487fd7fd52491b250c4afaa433801420cd907ac4a70ddb4589fdb99368b/merged/etc/grafana/grafana.ini is not directory

ERROR: for grafana  Cannot create container for service grafana: source /var/lib/docker/overlay2/4ac5b487fd7fd52491b250c4afaa433801420cd907ac4a70ddb4589fdb99368b/merged/etc/grafana/grafana.ini is not directory

Can anybody please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there are some problems with the volume configuration in your Grafana container:

First, I think this was simply a typo in your question:

```
      - grafana_ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.inianticipated location in container
```

I suspect that you were actually intending this:

```
      - grafana_ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini
```

Which doesn't make any sense: `grafana.ini` is a file, but a volume is
a directory. Docker won't allow you to mount a directory on top of a
file, hence the error:

```
ERROR: .../etc/grafana/grafana.ini is not directory
```

You have the same problem with the `grafana_data` volume, which you're
attempting to mount on top of `datasource.yml`:

```
      - grafana_data:/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/datasource.yml
```

I think you may be approaching this configuration in the wrong way;
you may want to read through these documents:

- https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/installation/docker/
- https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/configure-docker/
- https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/provisioning/

It is possible to configure Grafana (and Prometheus!) using only bind
mounts and environment variables (this includes installing plugin,
data sources, and dashboards), so you don't need to build your own
custom images.

---

Unrelated to this particular problem, there are some other things in
your `docker-compose.yml` that are worth changing.  You should no
longer be using the `links` directive...

```
    links:
      - prometheus
```

...because Docker maintains DNS for you automatically; your containers
can refer to each other by name with no additional configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem that can cause a similar error, is when mixing up the file name extensions. Be mindful to not refer to them as `.yaml` in the `docker-compose.yml` file, when you've actually used `.yml`. Or vice versa.

For example, you have the following file:

- `grafana_datasources.yml`

Then don't do (**.yaml**):

```yaml
./evidently_service/config/grafana_datasources.yaml:/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/grafana_datasources.yaml
```

Do this instead (**.yml**):

```yaml
./evidently_service/config/grafana_datasources.yml:/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/grafana_datasources.yml
```